# Why there are two servers listed in websphere portal console

Tags: websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

When I login to websphere portal console and go under Servers  -> Application Servers --> I see two servers listed: `server1` and `Websphere_Portal`. Why are there two servers? There is only one portal server here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right there is only one Portal server, but there is a second server there. If I recall correctly server1 basically just runs the admin console. It doesn't have Portal running on it.

Quote from some change notes for version 8,

> In previous releases, you needed to start WebSphere Application Server server1 before you can start WebSphere Portal. server1 was also needed to access the WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD001/overview/change_portal.html